# are plants objects?

Tags: word-usage

Are trees and other plants considered objects?
What about fruit and vegetables?

I am asking because the dictionaries define object as not-living or not alive thing. But fruit, vegetables and plants are living things.

I tried a google search, but could not find an answer quickly.

Comment: "I am asking because the dictionaries define object as not-living or not alive thing" - what dictionary?  I have checked several dictionaries, and the only one that says anything about an object not being a living thing is the [Cambridge Dictionary, which says](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/object) "not **usually** a living animal, plant, or person".

Comment: If you are decorating your house, plants can be viewed as objects.

Comment: Without consulting the dictionary, an object is **any** physical thing.  A car *is* an object.  An eyeball *is* an object.  My uncle *is* an object.  So they are *considered* objects.  Whether or not they are **referred** to as objects is nicely addressed by Jay below.  My uncle may also be a fool but that doesn't mean I refer to him as a fool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a classic problem with dictionary definitions: Sometimes it can be difficult to say whether to interpret them loosely or strictly.

When someone says that "object" refers to non-living things, they are mainly thinking "not people or animals".

If someone wropte, "When I entered the room, I saw three objects: a chair, a lamp, and the salesman", I think a reader would find that confusing or strange. "You're counting the salesman as an object? Is the salesman a robot or something?"

Maybe just a shade less strange would be, "When I entered the room, I saw three objects: a chair, a lamp, and a dog." Most would think it strange to refer to a dog as an "object".

But, "When I entered the room, I saw three objects: a chair, a lamp, and a potted plant" ... I think few would question that. Some might say that they wouldn't refer to a plant as an "object", but I don't think anyone would be surprised or confused if you did.

Note that "object" can also mean "goal" or "focus of attention". So it is perfectly reasonable to say, "The object of his attack was Senator Jones" or "Sally was the object of my affection". But that's a completely different definition of object.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, like most definitions of most words in most languages, depends on context.

If I am walking through a wood, I certainly don't regard the trees and other plants around me as objects. But if I am walking through a garden centre and see a row of plants in pots, next to tools and gardening supplies, then I might well regard them as objects.

So the answer is, Not usually, but in some contexts yes.

Remember that dictionaries record the language, they don't define it.